# installing PHP 5.5 on netbeans IDE 7.2.1

Tags: php, netbeans, netbeans-7

how to install PHP 5.5 on netbeans IDE (autocomplete, coloring etc.)? The version is 7.2.1.

Comment: I do not think you could deal with it (at least in a easy way), until the IDE itself will be upgraded, though they have support for 5.4 version, if 5.5 is something very different from it? And it looks like Netbeans 7.3 already in a stable stage, did you check it out?

Comment: @dmi3y What should I do? Is there any IDE that supports PHP 5.5?

Comment: I am going to see it right now, though I do not think it will have support for 5.5 yet, you could look for some another IDE or work with 5.4 settings which should be good in many cases (that's not mean you could not use 5.5 features in the code;)) http://php.net/manual/en/migration55.changes.php

Comment: probably php storm have something, but not sure, it is second favorite editor after Netbeans for me:)

Comment: okay, checked 7.3 have not yet support for 5.5

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but...

Support for PHP 5.5 will be in version 8.0, scheduled to come out next month.  However, the [release candidate](http://download.netbeans.org/netbeans/8.0/rc/) is already out and ready to be used.

EDIT:

[Netbeans 8.0 is out](http://dlc.sun.com.edgesuite.net/netbeans/8.0/final/) and it supports PHP 5.5.

Comment: 8.1 Beta already is available but is buggy, I couldn't change it yet for 7.4